# Cpp : Is there a way to avoid creating header files in this case?

Tags: c++

I have an abstract class called Screen :

```
class Screen {
public:
    virtual void init() = 0;
    virtual void update(float dt) = 0;
    virtual void handleInputs(ScreenManager* screenManager) = 0;
    virtual void dispose() = 0;
};
```

And every time I want to create a new Screen I have to:
1 : Create a header file :
Ex :

```
class MenuScreen : public Screen {
public:
    void init() override;
    void update(float dt) override;
    void handleInputs(ScreenManager* screenManager) override;
    void dispose() override;
};
```

2 : Create a cpp file :

```
void MenuScreen::init() {

}

void MenuScreen::update(float dt) {
    
}

void MenuScreen::handleInputs(ScreenManager* screenManager) {
    
}

void MenuScreen::dispose() {

}
```

Now my problem is I have so many screens , and every time I want to create a new Screen I have to copy and past the header file and all what I have to change is the class name , is there a better way to do that ? am I doing that right ? any help would be appreciated.

---

Comment: Do all your derived classes (eg `MenuScreen`) have different behaviours ?

Comment: Why exactly can you not put all the code into one header file and one cpp file? You are not forced to create one header and one cpp file for every class. When the classes are closely related it's perfectly sensible to combine them into a single header and single cpp file.

Comment: ***Now my problem is I have so many screens , and every time I want to create a new Screen I have to copy and past the header file and all what I have to change is the class name , is there a better way to do that ?*** Why do you have many? What is different between them? What do you consider many? A thousand? A hundred?

Comment: what. is the difference between the different screen types, please show another one (or 2)

Comment: They only have different members . For example the menu screen may have some (Buttons, Sliders ...) , and another screen VideoEditorScreen may have (VideoPlayer ...)

Comment: @drescherjm why do I have many, The Application I am working on , requires me to have a MenuScreen , VedioEditorScreen, NewProjectScreen...    , How many , a thousand , a Hundred ? , No not that much. What is the difference between them ? Thy only have different members .

Comment: What you'll probably find is that you have only four or five truly unique types and the rest of the differences between the screens can be managed by configuring member variables. This is like having a class for sword, axe, mace, etc... when all of them have identical program behaviour but do different damage, have a different descriptive text or graphic, etc..., attributes that can all be handled by configuring instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to put all the code in seperate files. If many screens are related or if they are part of a group, you could put them in a single file. You may also use seperate files only for big classes with a lot of code